# How i can convert User to FieldUserValue inside my CSOM code

Tags: development, csom, person-or-group

I have the following CSOM code:

```
Group group = web.SiteGroups.GetByName(subsitename);                     
List<FieldUserValue> currentgroupUsers = new List<FieldUserValue>();
foreach (User user2 in group.Users)
{
     currentgroupUsers.Add(***********);
}
```

So how I can convert/cast a `User` object to `FieldUserValue` object?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need `FieldUserValue` object? maybe there is another workaround for what you are trying yo achieve.

Comment: @GaneshSanap i need it as `List<FieldUserValue> ` because i will assign the `currentgroupUsers` to a field of type people or group which accept multiple entries..

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan the link is using server-sdie object while i am using CSOM, and in cSOM the FieldUserValue does not accept this `new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, listItem["Author"].ToString())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
List<FieldUserValue> currentgroupUsers = new List<FieldUserValue>();

foreach (User user2 in group.Users)
{
    var userLookupValue = new FieldLookupValue { LookupId = user2.Id };
    currentgroupUsers.Add(userLookupValue);
}

oListItem["PersonOrGroupField"] = currentgroupUsers.ToArray();
oListItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Hi.
I'm doing this and the value sets, but on update & ExecuteQuery, value restores to previous value.
I'm doing on a DocumentLibrary, not a simple list.
Any suggestions?